# Pandas dataframe: Replace multiple rows based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to replace some values in one dataframe's column with values from another data frame's column. Here's what the data frames look like. `df2` has a lot of rows and columns.

```
df1

    0                   1029
0   aaaaa               Green
1   bbbbb               Green
2   fffff               Blue
3   xxxxx               Blue
4   zzzzz               Green

df2
    0       1   2     3  ....    1029
0   aaaaa   1   NaN   14         NaN
1   bbbbb   1   NaN   14         NaN
2   ccccc   1   NaN   14         Blue
3   ddddd   1   NaN   14         Blue
...    
25  yyyyy   1   NaN   14         Blue
26  zzzzz   1   NaN   14         Blue
```

The final df should look like this

```
    0       1   2     3  ....    1029
0   aaaaa   1   NaN   14         Green 
1   bbbbb   1   NaN   14         Green
2   ccccc   1   NaN   14         Blue
3   ddddd   1   NaN   14         Blue
...    
25  yyyyy   1   NaN   14         Blue
26  zzzzz   1   NaN   14         Green
```

So basically what needs to happen is that `df1[0]` and `df[2]` need to be matched and then `df2[1029]` needs to have values replaced by the corresponding row in `df1[1029]` for the rows that matched. I don't want to lose any values in `df2['1029']` which are not in `df1['1029']`

I believe the `re` module in python can do that? This is what I have so far:

```
import re
for line in replace:
line = re.sub(df1['1029'], 
              '1029',
              line.rstrip())

print(line)
```

But it definitely doesn't work.

I could also use merge as in `merged1 = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')` but that doesn't replace the values inline.

Comment: @Minion I don't think so because that solution doesn't give you an inline replacement of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['aaaaa','bbbbb','fffff','xxxxx','zzzzz'], '1029':['Green','Green','Blue','Blue','Green']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['aaaa','bbbb','ccccc','ddddd','yyyyy','zzzzz',], '1029':[None,None,'Blue','Blue','Blue','Blue']})


# Fill NaNs
df2['1029'] = df2['1029'].fillna(df1['1029'])

# Merge the dataframes 
df_ = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on=['0'])

df_['1029'] = np.where(df_['1029_y'].isna(), df_['1029_x'], df_['1029_y'])

df_.drop(['1029_y','1029_x'],1,inplace=True)
print(df_)
```

Output:

```
       0   1029
0   aaaa  Green
1   bbbb  Green
2  ccccc   Blue
3  ddddd   Blue
4  yyyyy   Blue
5  zzzzz  Green
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the output should be all of the columns originally in `df2`. You're missing those values.

Comment: it will give you all columns as I have created df2 with only 2 columns, output only contains 2 columns

Comment: Ah, yes I see. I got this to work but is there any way where the `1029` column could stay in it's position as column 3 and not get moved to the end of `df_`? I'm trying to keep it's positionality.

Comment: you can do it by using `df_.reindex_axis(df2.columns, axis=1)`

Comment: That didn't work, but this did: `df_.insert(loc=idx, column='1209_n', value=new_col)` where idx was the position and value was the column I wanted moved.

Comment: great that you got it working. But I dont understand downvote on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['aa','bb','ff','xx', 'zz'], '1029':['Green', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Green']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'0':['aa','bb','cc','dd','ff','gg','hh','xx','yy', 'zz'], '1': [1]*10, '2': [np.nan]*10, '1029':[np.nan, np.nan, 'Blue', 'Blue', np.nan, np.nan, 'Blue', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Blue']})
df1
    0   1029
0  aa  Green
1  bb  Green
2  ff   Blue
3  xx   Blue
4  zz  Green

df2
    0  1   1029   2
0  aa  1    NaN NaN
1  bb  1    NaN NaN
2  cc  1   Blue NaN
3  dd  1   Blue NaN
4  ff  1    NaN NaN
5  gg  1    NaN NaN
6  hh  1   Blue NaN
7  xx  1  Green NaN
8  yy  1   Blue NaN
9  zz  1   Blue NaN
```

If the column '0' in both the data frames is sorted, this will work.

```
df2.loc[(df2['1029'].isna() & df2['0'].isin(df1['0'])), '1029'] = df1['1029'][df2['0'].isin(df1['0'])].tolist()

df2
    0  1   1029   2
0  aa  1  Green NaN
1  bb  1  Green NaN
2  cc  1   Blue NaN
3  dd  1   Blue NaN
4  ff  1  Green NaN
5  gg  1    NaN NaN
6  hh  1   Blue NaN
7  xx  1  Green NaN
8  yy  1   Blue NaN
9  zz  1   Blue NaN
```

Comment: I understand how this logic works but I'm getting the error `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match` Can't seem to find a way around it